# sleeping barber giving deadlock

Tags: c, multithreading, deadlock

I wrote the code for sleeping barber problem and it seems to be looking weird...
the code is as follows..

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<pthread.h>

#define MAX_C 10
int a[MAX_C], head=0, tail=0, tmp, tb, tc, count=1;
pthread_mutex_t B;
double time_slot[]={0.125,0.5,0.75,1.00,1.25,1.50,1.75,2.00};

void wait(int a)
{
    clock_t g=clock();
    while(((float)(clock()-g))/CLOCKS_PER_SEC != time_slot[a]);
}

void barber()
{
    printf("barber started\n");
    while(1) {
        tmp=0;
        while(head==tail) {
            printf("b\n");
        }
        tb=rand()%8;
        printf("tail:%d\n", tail);
        tail=(tail+1)%MAX_C;
        wait(tb);
    }
}

void customer()
{       
    printf("customers started\n");
    while(1) {
        wait(rand()%8);
        while((head+1)%MAX_C == tail) {
            printf("c\n");
        }
        a[head]=count-1;
        printf("head:%d\n", head);
        head=(head+1)%MAX_C;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    pthread_t b,c;

    pthread_mutex_init(&B, NULL);
    pthread_create(&c, NULL, (void*)&customer, NULL);
    pthread_create(&b, NULL, (void*)&barber, NULL);

    pthread_join(b, NULL);
    pthread_join(c, NULL);  
    exit(0);
}
```

The problem is that when the buffer is full ... the barber is waiting for customers... but the customer is not executing at all!!( it is neither waiting nor filling the buffer)... coz the customers while loop was not executing...

Comment: Your thread function prototypes should be `void* function (void*)`

Comment: Also this cannot be a deadlock as such as you never actually lock your mutex anywhere that I can see

Comment: Does it enter `customer` at all? I.e. do the first `printf` statement get executed? Have you tried running it in a debugger, putting a breakpoint in `customer` and stepped through it to see what is happening?

Comment: @mathematician1975 I think thats not at all a problem here.... and of course i dont know what to call this kind of problem...

Comment: @Joachim I ran it and the customer function is executing...

Comment: You are modifying 2 global variables without synchronisation and these variables are used to control loop logic. Your code as it stands is not possible to predict in a meaningful way. You should perhaps consider mutex protecting your code when you change `head` and `tail`. Unless I am completely misunderstanding something here of course...

Comment: Yeah, I tried that one also.. Actually i think mutexes should be used only when two processes try to access same variable .. thats not happening here..

Comment: With `while(((float)(clock()-g))/CLOCKS_PER_SEC != time_slot[a])`, the wait could be quite long if the OS kicks in at the wrong time. Perhaps you should test `< time_slot[a]` instead.

Comment: @nitish - But they *are* accessing both `head` and `tail`, like in `while(head==tail)`.

Comment: @BoPersson    that wasn't making any difference... ( whether u keep mutex or not..) i still keep getting the same thing...

Comment: @DanielFischer also it's not a mistake to write that way... coz we are comparing jst the difference between the clock ticks which is indpt of whether the thread runs or remains in sleep state...

Comment: @nitish712 (Very) Unlikely to happen, but if the `while` misses the correct `clock()` value, it would loop until it wraps (if `clock_t` is an integral type, doomsday if `clock_t` is a floating point type). Using `<` is just a bit more defensive.

Comment: @Daneil Then why is that exactly happening after the whole buffer has filled??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Daneil Fischer said ... there was a mistake with `while(((float)(clock()-g))/CLOCKS_PER_SEC != time_slot[a]);` i should replace it with

> `while(((float)(clock()-g))/CLOCKS_PER_SEC <= time_slot[a]);`

But its still weird that this 'missing' of the clock value is occuring only after the whole buffer is filled....

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem in the semaphores that the executer are using the CPU

Please see if you are using the semaphores very well.
Don´t forget the  #include

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

// The maximum number of customer threads.
#define MAX_CUSTOMERS 25
</b>

void *customer(void *number) {
    int num = *(int *)number;

    // Leave for the shop and take some random amount of
    // time to arrive.
    printf("Customer %d leaving for barber shop.\n", num);
    randwait(5);
    printf("Customer %d arrived at barber shop.\n", num);

    // Wait for space to open up in the waiting room...
    sem_wait(&waitingRoom);
    printf("Customer %d entering waiting room.\n", num);

    // Wait for the barber chair to become free.
    sem_wait(&barberChair);

    // The chair is free so give up your spot in the
    // waiting room.
    sem_post(&waitingRoom);

    // Wake up the barber...
    printf("Customer %d waking the barber.\n", num);
    sem_post(&barberPillow);

    // Wait for the barber to finish cutting your hair.
    sem_wait(&seatBelt);

    // Give up the chair.
    sem_post(&barberChair);
    printf("Customer %d leaving barber shop.\n", num);
}

void *barber(void *junk) {
    // While there are still customers to be serviced...
    // Our barber is omnicient and can tell if there are 
    // customers still on the way to his shop.
    while (!allDone) {

    // Sleep until someone arrives and wakes you..
    printf("The barber is sleeping\n");
    sem_wait(&barberPillow);

    // Skip this stuff at the end...
    if (!allDone) {

        // Take a random amount of time to cut the
        // customer's hair.
        printf("The barber is cutting hair\n");
        randwait(3);
        printf("The barber has finished cutting hair.\n");

        // Release the customer when done cutting...
        sem_post(&seatBelt);
    }
    else {
        printf("The barber is going home for the day.\n");
    }
    }
}
```